# How to automate adding factors to variables in large data frame in R

Tags: r, function, label, factors, pmap

I have a large data frame in R with over 200 mostly character variables that I would like to add factors for. I have prepared all levels and labels in an separate data frame. For a certain variable `Var1`, the corresponding levels and labels are `Var1_v` and `Var1_b`, for example for the variable `Gender` the levels and labels are named `Gender_v` and `Gender_l`.

Here is an example of my data:

```
df <- data.frame (Gender = c("2","2","1","2"),
                  AgeG = c("3","1","4","2"))

fct <- data.frame (Gender_v  = c("1", "2"),
                  Gender_b = c("Male", "Female"),
                  AgeG_v = c("1","2","3","4"),
                  AgeG_b = c("<25","25-60","65-80",">80"))

df$Gender <- factor(df$Gender, levels = fct$Gender_v, labels = fct$Gender_b, exclude = NULL)
df$AgeG <- factor(df$AgeG, levels = fct$AgeG_v, labels = fct$AgeG_b, exclude = NULL)
```

Is there away to automatize the process, so that the factors (levels and labels) are applied to corresponding variables without having me doing every single one individually?
I think it's done through a function probebly with `pmap`.

My goal is minimize the effort needed for this process. Is there a better way to prepare the labels and levels as well?

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: There is the option `stringsAsFactors` in the creation of data frames. This may be useful earlier in your data pipeline. The error in your example code is due to your Gender_v and AgeG_v being stored as character values instead of numerical values. Your current code works when `Gender_v  = c(1,2)` i.e. no quotation marks.

Comment: @typewriter How should `stringsAsFactors` exactly help?
I am not running any error in my code btw. It is just inefficient when you have to run it to over 200 variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A data frame is not really an appropriate data structure for storing the
factor level definitions in: there’s no reason to expect all factors to have
an equal amount of levels. Rather, I’d just use a plain list, and store the
level information more compactly as named vectors, along these lines:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  Gender = c("2", "2", "1", "2"),
  AgeG = c("3", "1", "4", "2")
)

value_labels <- list(
  Gender = c("Male" = 1, "Female" = 2),
  AgeG = c("<25" = 1, "25-60" = 2, "65-80" = 3, ">80" = 4)
)
```

Then you can make a function that uses that data structure to make factors
in a data frame:

```r
make_factors <- function(data, value_labels) {
  for (var in names(value_labels)) {
    if (var %in% colnames(data)) {
      vl <- value_labels[[var]]
      data[[var]] <- factor(
        data[[var]],
        levels = unname(vl),
        labels = names(vl)
      )
    }
  }
  data
}

make_factors(df, value_labels)
#>   Gender  AgeG
#> 1 Female 65-80
#> 2 Female   <25
#> 3   Male   >80
#> 4 Female 25-60
```

Comment: Thanks Mikko. I have changed one thing in your code to make it easier.
I have switched the positions of the levels and labels to make it for example `1 = 'Male'` instead of `'Male' = 1`, and changed the function accordingly `levels = names(vl), labels = unname(vl)`.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with a simple refactoring of your code, automatizing thought a loop. The more data you add, the better your time spent. I believe this  `fct[[paste0(names(df[i]),"_v")]]` can be refactored in an small function to look even better

```
> df <- data.frame (Gender = c("2","2","1","2"),
+                   AgeG = c("3","1","4","2"))
> 
> fct <- data.frame (Gender_v  = c("1", "2"),
+                    Gender_b = c("Male", "Female"),
+                    AgeG_v = c("1","2","3","4"),
+                    AgeG_b = c("<25","25-60","65-80",">80"))
> 
> for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
+   
+   le <- fct[[paste0(names(df[i]),"_v")]]
+   
+   la <- fct[[paste0(names(df[i]),"_b")]]
+   
+   df[,i] <- factor(df[,i],levels = le ,labels = la,exclude = NULL)
+   
+ }
> 
> df
  Gender  AgeG
1 Female 65-80
2 Female   <25
3   Male   >80
4 Female 25-60
>
```

Edit: Here is the if condition added

```
> df <- data.frame (Gender_f = c("2","2","1","2"),
+                             AgeG_f = c("3","1","4","2"),
+                   AgeN = c(70,15,96,30))
> 
> fct <- data.frame (Gender_v  = c("1", "2"),
+                                   Gender_b = c("Male", "Female"),
+                                   AgeG_v = c("1","2","3","4"),
+                                  AgeG_b = c("<25","25-60","65-80",">80"))
> 
> for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
+ 
+   if(endsWith(names(df[i]),"_f")){
+     
+     name <- str_remove(names(df[i]),"_f")
+   
+     le <- fct[[paste0(name,"_v")]]
+    
+     la <- fct[[paste0(name,"_b")]]
+      
+     df[,i] <- factor(df[,i],levels = le ,labels = la,exclude = NULL)
+   
+   }
+      
+ }
> 
> df
  Gender_f AgeG_f AgeN
1   Female  65-80   70
2   Female    <25   15
3     Male    >80   96
4   Female  25-60   30
>
```

Comment: Thanks.
You methods works flawlessly with the example, but does not with my data. 

The problem in your code is probably the assumption that there is a factor, a level and a label for each variable. But this is not true. This turns other values in other variables into missings.

Comment: Yes, you are correct ! 
Just asking, if the variable is a factor, you will always have 2 entries in the fct data frame ? Because in that case, with an if condition it's solved.

Comment: Yes I guess. There should be 2 entries in the fct data frame for each variable.

I was thinking about a method, that looks at the name of a variable in the df data frame, then adds "_v" and "_b" to create the factor for this variable from the fct data frame.

How would you add the if condition btw. I more experienced in SAS than R.

Comment: I was wondering, what would also differ if I added a label for an NA level?

Comment: I edited it with the if condition added !

Comment: Based on your response, my recommendation would be to just create or read the variables. After that, I would transform variables within an specific pattern like ending with "_f" to factors using as.factor(). That is all ! Really simple.